# Discord bot delete messages

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I wanna delete messages with bot. I wrote some easy codes but I got some errors.

my codes :

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "clear") {
    msg.delete(100)
    msg.channel.send("100 messages have been deleted!")
}
```

nodejs version is v12.16.3

Comment: What do you want to achieve and what is the error?

Comment: I want to delete a certain amount of messages by commanding the bot.Error : https://hastebin.com/yobuhojonu.rb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
if (msg.content.toLowerCase() === prefix + "clear") {
    const channel = msg.channel; // TextChannel object
    const messageManager = channel.messages; // MessageManager object

    messageManager.fetch({ limit: 100 }).then((messages) => {
        // `messages` is a Collection of Message objects
        messages.forEach((message) => {
            message.delete();
        });

        channel.send("100 messages have been deleted!");
    });
}
```

Reading the docs is very helpful in this case.

- TextChannel: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=messages
- MessageManager: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageManager?scrollTo=fetch
- Message: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=delete

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I run the command, "100 messages have been deleted!" constantly spamming his article. I want it to be written only once. How can I do that?

Comment: Oups this needs to be moved outside of the `forEach` loop. I edited my answer.